# How to increase waiting time in a flow from 30 days to 90 days

Tags: power-automate, powerapps-forms

How to increase waiting time in approval  a flow from 30 days and After 30 days, any pending steps time-out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum run time for a Power Automate flow is 30 days, this cannot be extended. However you can implement an approval process that lasts more than 30 days using multiple flows. One flow starts the approval process and a second flow triggers when users approve or reject.

Do a search for "power automate long running approvals" and you will find lots of resources that cover the topic.